# Android Applandeo Calendar Date Picker Mode

Tags: android, datepicker

I am back with one more problem for which I need help.
I am developing an android application, Where I've used Applandeo Calendar Library. Now the problem is I want to change the datePicker mode(Single, Range, Multiple) programmatically with OptionsMenu, but I didn't find any method in Applandeo Library to achieve this task. Can any one help me how to achieve my Task?? 
(Or)
Suggest me library where I can change Date picker modes programmatically and also Can add and show the Events in calendar...
Any help would be grateful.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cadar to add and show events in calendar. It represents month and list calendars views and possibility to display events.

Example:

Add to your app gradle:

```
compile 'io.github.memfis19:cadar:0.4.8'
```

Add to your layout:

```
<io.github.memfis19.cadar.view.MonthCalendar
    android:id="@+id/monthCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Using in code:

```
MonthCalendarConfiguration.Builder builder = new 
MonthCalendarConfiguration.Builder(this);
monthCalendar.setCalendarPrepareCallback(this);
monthCalendar.prepareCalendar(builder.build());

monthCalendar.setOnDayChangeListener(new OnDayChangeListener() {
@Override
  public void onDayChanged(Calendar calendar) {
    Toast.makeText(MonthCalendarActivity.this, 
   calendar.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
monthCalendar.setOnMonthChangeListener(new OnMonthChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onMonthChanged(Calendar calendar) {
    Toast.makeText(MonthCalendarActivity.this, 
    calendar.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
...

@Override
public void onCalendarReady(CalendarController calendar) {
monthCalendar.displayEvents(events, new DisplayEventCallback() {
@Override
 public void onEventsDisplayed() {

  }
 });
}
```

At end Don't forget to release calendar:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    monthCalendar.releaseCalendar();
}
```

You can refer this demo at: https://github.com/memfis19/Cadar#for-more-specific-using-please-look-at-sample-project

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rakshit.. I need to change the date picker mode also. Is that Possible with this library????

Comment: @MadhuKumar Yes you can customize the date picker view in this lib.

Comment: @MadhuKumar Please accept and upvote my answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: I Downladed the code from GitHub and tried to open in Android studio, I am getting error            Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.

Comment: I didn't find the picker modes in this library.., can we customize them??? If yes, please give me an example